# Twig, render template and send the template as emails, css and some imgs missing

Tags: php, css, email, symfony, twig

I have a template rendered by twig, it has some variables sent from twig, a css path included with hardcoded path, 3 logos from the same server, and 1 from another server. After the template is rendered, i sent it as emails to subscribers.

The main part of the template works fine, however, first on my phone, i can not see any content of the email (iphone 4s), on Mac outlook, it works, i can see content and all imgs, css works too. I tested with my gmail account, on my phone, i dont see content, on gmail web page, css doesnt work but i see the logos and other content.

Any ideas what is causing all these? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CSS files in e-mails. To be more precise, you can, but most of the e-mail clients (like Gmail) not supports it. Instead of a css file, you should use inline `<style>` tags for css styling.

Like this:

```
<h3 style="color: #1c70db;">NOW $159</h3>
```

Read this article, it is a good summary for e-mail sending:
[Using CSS in HTML Emails: The Real Story](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)

Here is the support table for CSS tags in different e-mail clients:
[The Ultimate Guide to CSS](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Hi thanks, i thought twig could cover the css. How about the logos?

Comment: @user3382722 if you use swiftmailer in Symfony you will be able to embed any picture in your email (e.g. logos, icons, ...) Take a look at http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-inline-media-files